# Esc key problem in a Mac keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mac

I'm using a Mac Bluetooth keyboard (model A1314) in my Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3, and it is fine except for the Esc key. Sometimes it works properly, others it doesn't work and others I need to press 3-5 times the key to have a response.

As you can imagine, it is very frustrating because when it doesn't work I need to press the inbuilt Esc key of my laptop, breaking my programming flux.

Today It was not working but recently it started to work intermittent, so I take advantage of it to run the xev command and got this result:

Mac keyboard:

> KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
> root 0x257, subw 0x0, time 20707755, (78,100), root:(2048,180),
> state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
> mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
> FilterEvent returns: False

Internal keyboard:

> KeyRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
> root 0x257, subw 0x0, time 20707861, (78,100), root:(2048,180),
> state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) " FilterEvent returns: False

It tried it also in my Android and the behavior was the same. In my windows partition it didn't work, but I think that in other moment it could work like in Ubuntu and Android.

I discard a hardware damage because all the other keys work perfectly, and it doesn't show any signal of damage.

What could be the problem? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your keyboard has a malfunctioning Esc key. `xev` outputs both show Esc is 0x1b, which it should be (see `man ascii`). Can you remove the keytop and clean carefully?

Comment: I'm sure it is not a hardware problem. Anyway, I did it and nothing changed. It is totally clean.